# showing Tiny MCE popup blank in WYSISYG

Tags: tinymce

Tiny MCE is popup sowing blank in WYSISYG editor.

[image]

Comment: try this https://piyushsuthar.wordpress.com/2015/07/13/add-wysiwyg-editor-in-custom-module-in-custom-module-admin/

Comment: You need check what show browser console. I think you can find error there.

Comment: Yes @AntonBelov i checked the console and it gives me below error  <br>              Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://www.website.com/js/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/link.htm does not permit framing.

Answer (score 1):

You try open frame using http window on https site. You should fix frame address or disable https. U can allso read this to get more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921676/does-not-permit-cross-origin-framing-iframe